# Can I Safely Delete Ubuntu's /boot Partition?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

Here is a picture of my current setup, [Picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPN8M.jpg) I have two questions. First; Can I safely delete the /boot partition because during the install I chose a lash drive for the boot loader?

Second question; What is that extended partition? I do know that the top is Windows 7 encrypted with PGP, second I have no idea, third is /root, and 4th is /home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot delete the /boot partition, at least not if you want the system to keep on booting!  The bootloader (GRUB) that you installed on a flash drive contains only enough code to find the Linux kernel and execute it.  You still need the kernel itself (vmlinuz) and its initial filesystem (initramfs) in order to boot the system.

As for the second question, an msdos (aka MBR) format partition table only has enough room for four entries, called "primary" partitions.  In order to have more than four **total** partitions, you need what's called an extended partition.  The partitions listed in an extended partition are known as "logical" partitions.  An extended partition is essentially a pointer to another place on disk which contains more partition table entries.  That pointer itself takes up one of the four primary partition entries, and thus appears in the gparted listing.

Comment: I am not fully understanding the extended partiton, I believe I have a MSDOS partition table and if so are you saying it can only have 4 (max) partitions? if so then why is Just that one named that? Do I have GRUB on my flash drive? how is /boot different form GRUB? Also can I safely encrypt the /boot partition through the command line, If so how? Thank you so much for the help and I apologize for all the questions. One more thing, What is the extended partition and what is inside it or being used for, can i encrypt it?

Comment: @Krea  An MSDOS partition table can only have four **primary** partitions.  In order to have more than four **total** partitions, you need an extended partition, which the Ubuntu installer created for you.  GRUB is the bootloader, it "contains only enough code to find the Linux kernel and execute it".  You cannot encrypt /boot because GRUB does not know how to decrypt it, that functionality is built into the kernel. But, no sensitive data is stored on /boot.  The extended partition is just a list of partitions, it cannot be encrypted, the partitions in that list can be (sda5 in your image).

Comment: Thank you so much, is there a way to put /boot on a flash drive?

Comment: @Krea, sure it is possible in principle.  That's probably best asked as a separate question though.

Comment: Okay thank you, um, in gparted it says I must create a new extended partition table to have more than 4, I would like to just partition free space for Kali. I don't know how to make a new extended.

Comment: @Krea  Unfortunately, it appears that the Ubuntu installer went and positioned your extended partition between two primary partitions.  While there is room for more logical partition entries in your extended partition, there is no unallocated data space in the extended partition.  You would need to move the extended partiton to the beginning of the unallocated area in order to create more logical partitions.

Comment: @Krea By the way, please accept the answer if you think it answers your original question.

Comment: is clicking: the up arrow (this answer is useful) accepting? How can I achieve this, Delete it? What would happen if I did?

Comment: @Krea Clicking the up arrow is upvoting the answer.  To accept the answer, click the check box below the voting arrows.  Here's the help link which explains it in more detail: http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers  Thanks!